# Run groovy scripts for jenkins in IDE

Tags: groovy, jenkins, ide

I wanted to run groovy scripts in my IDE instead of Jenkins Script console. is this possible? If so where i can download http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/ API so that i can put that in classpath.

I cannot refer hudson.model.* and other classes with jenkins CLI jar

Comment: Thanks for replying Mike. I have eclipse and IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

There is a webpage that explains how to configure Eclipse on how to [Write Groovy scripts for Jenkins with code completion](http://www.mdoninger.de/2011/11/07/write-groovy-scripts-for-jenkins-with-code-completion.html)

Short version:

- create a new maven project,
- add jenkins dependencies,
- update settings.xml to include jenkins repo,
- add Groovy support to Eclipse(optional),
- convert project to groovy and you're good to go.

BTW, for Eclipse Mars, the Groovy plugin is here: http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/